# Convert Crystal Reports Text Object/Text box to HTML?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I want to convert the text from Crystal reports to HTML and so far I have noticed that if I simply add a text field, I am able to change it to HTML by formatting text option and then under Paragraph tab there is an option to change the text interpretation. The problem is that I have entered text box to enter some hard coded information along with the database driven field, so I would like to know if there is a way I can convert the text box data into HTML. I am currently using crystal reports XI and want going forward want to upload these reports in a website using visual studio 2010. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the 'Text Interpretation' is ONLY a property of these fields:

- Database
- Formula
- Parameter
- Group Name

I wasn't able to get the Text Object to act as HTML.

However, you could create a formula with static HTML text:

```
"<strong>this is bold text</strong>"
```

Or a formula that combines text w/ data:

```
"<pre>" + {table.html_field} + "</pre>"
```

You could also use a string parameter to display user-supplied, HTML text.

Comment: Thanks, shall I add this in a text formula area? I was able to change all the database field in to HTML TEXT interpretation but any data that is coming from a formula, I am not able to change its interpretation. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what a 'text formula area' is.  If you use a Text Object (Insert | Text Object), you will loose the 'Text Interpretation' property.  You will need to create a Formula Field that uses one of two approaches that I describe in my answer.